# How to used each and push data to array in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, push, addition

How to add data to array ? i have form input with some option and i used button add more for add section form input. I want to make the options that have been selected not displayed in the rest of the index.
example :

1. index 0 i chose G05B-IA1
2. index 1 i chose G05B-IA2
3. index 2 i chose G05B-IA3

And I store it in an array. i want got result like this [G05B-IA1,G05B-IA2,G05B-IA3]
But, the result i got it is ['G05B-IA2', 'G05B-IA2', 'G05B-IA2']

[image: RESULT]

My Jquery Code

```
  $(document).on('change', '.slot_id', function(){
      cekslotid = $(this).val(); 
      console.log(cekslotid);
  });

  $(document).on('change', '.warehouse2', function(){
      var warehouseid = $(this).val(); 
      let idtarget  = $(this).data('idtarget');
      let cektarget = idtarget - 1;
      let slotid1   = $("#slot_id").val();
      let slotid2   = $("#slot_id"+cektarget+'').val();
      let data      = [slotid1];

  
  $('.slot_id').each(function() {
    data.push($(cekslotid).val());
  });

  console.log(data);
```

My HTML in view

```
<div class="add-more-pallet">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Pilih Gudang : </label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <select class="form-control" id="warehouse" required>
                                <option value="">-- Pilih Gudang --</option>
                                @foreach($warehouse as $row)
                                <option value="{{ $row->id_warehouse }}">{{ $row->warehouse_name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                           </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label>Pilih Pallet : </label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pallet"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <select class="form-control slot_id" id="slot_id" name="slot_id[]" required><option value="">-- Pilih Pallet --</option></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My HTML in Jquery

```
'<div class="col-md-6">' + 
                        '<label>Pilih Gudang : </label>' +
                        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                          '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                            '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></span>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<select class="form-control warehouse2" data-idtarget="'+i+'" required>' +
                            '<option value="">-- Pilih Gudang --</option>' +
                            '<option value="G05B">Gudang 05 B</option>' +
                            '<option value="G09">Gudang 09</option>' +
                          '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div class="col-md-5">' + 
                        '<label>Pilih Pallet : </label>' +
                        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                          '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                            '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pallet"></i></span>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<select id="slot_id'+i+'" class="form-control slot_id" name="slot_id['+i+']" data-idtarget="'+i+'" required><option value="">-- Pilih Pallet --</option></select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
```

What's wrong with my code ?
Why does the value stored in the array become double ?

Comment: First just do `data.push($(this).val());` second please include your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing the same value over and over, the one you set here

```
$(document).on('change', '.slot_id', function(){
  cekslotid = $(this).val(); 
});
```

Here is a working method

```
let data = $('.slot_id').map(function() { return this.value }).get();
```

Comment: it works, but, not working in my code. because, I use 2 class slot id, slot id for index 0 and slot id for index i. if I don't differentiate the slot id for index 0 and index i then the value entered into the array will be double

Comment: SHOW YOUR HTML! I cannot guess why you have two sets of slots. You can add a class and do `let data1 = $('.slot_id.slot1').map(function() { return this.value }).get(),let data2 = $('.slot_id.slot2').map(function() { return this.value }).get();`  or similar or use a filter

Comment: result from **$('.slot_id').map(function() { return this.value }).get();** is **['G05B-IA1', ' ']**, should be just ['G05B-IA1']. I think what makes a null value is the same class id slot naming

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML!!! You have two useless versions of your HTML - I cannot test your problem with the code you provide

Comment: Sorry, because the code is too much so I thought I'd just show the part where the problem occurred. I'll try to solve it, thanks for the help

Comment: thanks it worked, I made the data var global and I moved the data = $('.slot_id').map(function() { return this.value }).get(); into class slot id